# KnockoutJS - assign js object to viewmodel observable

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I need to assign a javascript object to a ko observable.
This object has 75 properties and if I write something like this:

```
viewmodel.myprop(obj);
```

it takes very very time and web page crashes.

I thought a work around using a for loop iterating on object properties but I can't write correctly assignment instruction:

```
for(property in obj){
    // ????
}
```

How can I do this?

Thank you

Comment: I'm not able to understand the exact problem you have. Are you setting all 75 properties at the same time, causing a certain computed property to be calculated 75 times in that very short timespan? If so, using a loop won't fix the problem; [Change observable but don't notify subscribers in knockout.js](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17983118/247702) might be of use.

Comment: I agree there must be some other race condition in effect. Setting an Object as an observable value should not cause a problem like this.

Comment: How can I debug knockoutjs assignment?

Answer (score 0):

In this code properties are dynamically creating

```
for (property in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
          //here you can check all the values on each properties
          console.log(property +" - "+obj[property]);
          //Here new properties are registering for viewmodel
          this[property] = ko.observable(obj[property]); 
      }
 }
 console.log(this.MyProperty());
```

MyProperty is some matching property name on your large object.

Comment: I need to assign obj to viewmodel.myprop() but in a different way of viewmodel.myprop(obj)

Comment: just tried but nothing to do. In particular viewmodel prop is valorized (if I check in console) but in page there are no effects.

Comment: It works for me in my sample app.In console also I can see the property value.I feel you missed something.I edited the code again.Please check it.