# Update value to the database only when changed by user or suspend certain subscription if value changed by code

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, typescript

From the viewmodel I want to update value to the server straight after it was changed in the view.

```
class OrderLine
{
    itemCode: KnockoutObservable<string>;
    itemName: KnockoutObservable<string>;

    constructor(code: string, name: string)
    {
        this.itemCode = ko.observable(code);
        this.itemName = ko.observable(code);
        //subscribers
        this.itemCode.subscribe(this.updateCode, this, "change");
        this.itemName.subscribe(this.updateName, this, "change");
    }

    updateCode = (newvalue: string) =>
    {
        //Update value to the server
    }

    updateName = (newvalue: string) =>
    {
        //Update value to the server
    }
}
```

Both values can be changed by user and with explicit subscriptions updating to the server/database works fine.

In the server side when updating `itemCode` will update value of `itemName` too. So response to the client will return `json` object with new value for `itemName`

Here i have a problem, because changing value of `itemName` in the viewmodel will fire a subscription callback method which will update same value to the server again

```
    updateCode = (newvalue: string) =>
    {
        //Update value to the server
        //in the handler of the successful request
        this.itemName(updatedvaluefromServer);   //-- this trigger another request   
    }
```

Question: is it possible to change value of `KnockoutObservable` which will notify only view subscribers?
Or is it possible to detect that value was changed from the view?

I tried used "sneaky update" by @RPNiemeyer from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/17984353/1565525
but this approach will suspend all subscribers from being notified, including view's subscribers

Comment: So I understand: the two variables are not independent, but you can update either one and the server should just update the other one? This kind of dependency suggests using a computed for one of them (either one) and make it writable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a pattern that utilizes a computed observable backed by a regular observable:

```
class OrderLine
{
    private _itemCode: KnockoutObservable<string>;
    private _itemName: KnockoutObservable<string>;
    itemCode: KnockoutComputed<string>;
    itemName: KnockoutComputed<string>;

    constructor(code: string, name: string)
    {
        this._itemCode = ko.observable(code);
        this._itemName = ko.observable(code);

        this.itemCode = ko.computed({
            read: () => this._itemCode(),
            write: (newValue) => {
                this._itemCode(newValue);
                // Update server
                // In the handler of the successful request:
                this._itemName("...");
            }
        });

        this.itemName = ko.computed({
            read: () => this._itemName(),
            write: (newValue) => {
                this._itemName(newValue);
                // Update server
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In the callback on succesful Ajax calls you update the *backing* observable, not the `write` in the computed, as to prevent the problem you're having.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I was talking about. `code` is a normal observable, and `name` is a writable computed. When `code` is updated, the read value of `name` will be updated. When `name` is written to, `code` is updated, which updates the read value of `name`. Only the update of the read value is a change in the observable value of `name`, so there are not two updates to `name`.

If you watch the console, you will see that updating either of the fields generates one update to each of them.

```js
function orderLine(code, name) {
  return {
    code: code,
    name: name
  };
}
var serverValues = [
  orderLine(1, 'one'),
  orderLine(2, 'two'),
  orderLine(3, 'three')
];

function getNameFromCode(code) {
  var found = ko.utils.arrayFilter(serverValues, function(line) {
    return line.code == code;
  });
  if (found.length == 0) return '';
  return found[0].name;
}

function getCodeFromName(name) {
  var found = ko.utils.arrayFilter(serverValues, function(line) {
    return line.name == name;
  });
  if (found.length == 0) return '';
  return found[0].code;
}

function vm() {
  var self = {};
  self.code = ko.observable();
  self.name = ko.computed({
    read: function() {
      return getNameFromCode(self.code());
    },
    write: function(newValue) {
      console.debug("Writing code");
      self.code(getCodeFromName(newValue));
    }
  });

  self.code.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    console.debug("Updating code to:", newValue);
  });
  self.name.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    console.debug("Updating name to:", newValue);
  });

  return self;
}

ko.applyBindings(vm());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<label>Code</label>
<input data-bind="value:code" />
<br />
<label>Name</label>
<input data-bind="value:name" />
```