# Change observable but don't notify subscribers in knockout.js (TypeScript)

Tags: typescript, knockout.js, observable

Is there a way to override `notifySubscribers` in TypeScript version of knockout.js ?

What I want exactly is a TypeScript version of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17984353/7296938
Because with that code, I get `TS2339: Property 'withPausing' does not exist on type 'ObservableFunctions<any>'`

Comment: If you want to do something that works in JavaScript, but does not compile in TypeScript you can always use // @ts-ignore.

Comment: I agree with you, but I'm looking for a way to do it natively in TS