# Knockoutjs: notify extender with custom predicate

Tags: knockout.js

Does knockoutjs have a way to conditionally fire manual subscriptions?

According to docs I can use the notify extender to control when get notified of a changes in an observable, for example to always fire subscriptions like this: `yourObservable.extend({ notify: 'always' });`

What I want to know is if that is there a way to condition when to fire nofication not only with strings as above but with a custom predicate or some observable value like this: `yourObservable.extend({ notify: myPredicateOrObservable });`

Comment: I think you can write a custom extension that overwrites `notifySubscribers` like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17984353/3297291). Like Niemeyer states, I think it's probably a bad idea though. Could you clarify _why_ you want to do this? There might be other solutions to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the `yourObservable.valueHasMutated()` function?